# Cannot connect to localhost using Socket io example

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io, chat

I have been following along to the socket io chat example and I CANNOT get it to connect to the localhost! I have done it over and over again and it is really frustrating. Here is the example I have been following:

http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Here is the index:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
      $('form').submit(function(){
        socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
        $('#m').val('');
        return false;
      });
      socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

here is index.js :

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

and here is the package.json :

```
{
  "name": "socket-chat-example",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "my first socket.io app",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.10.2",
    "socket.io": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

I've tried everything and it always gives:

> "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

and even node `index.js` will not even start listening!

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure this is the problem, but the socket.io documentation for use with Express 4 suggests this and this is what I'm successfully using with Express and socket.io in my app:

```
var app = require('express').createServer();
var server = app.listen(3000);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

And, of course when you put the URL into the browser, you have to include the `:3000` port number.

If you need further help, please tell us what exact resource is not being found that causes the error: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)".